# Javascript Regular Expression for allowing multiple phone numbers in text box

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text box in which i want user to provide multiple mobile numbers, each number should be only 10 digits and they should be comma separated. Other than comma no special character should be allowed not even space.

Comment: What if my phone had 12 digits, your website won't accept me? potential buyer lost.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer NO! GO AWAY

Comment: Do you want to validate the whole string as one or just capture those phone numbers which match your rule?

Comment: @garyh: I have to validate the whole string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume you can figure out how to get the value out of the textbox.

Here's a regex that'll do the number validation:

```
/^(\d{10}(,\d{10})*)?$/
```

This will allow the field to be blank, but if something is entered it would have to be one or more 10-digit numbers separated by commas.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ - Depends on your point of view. The OP doesn't really make it clear whether it's valid to provide no phone number at all, so I decided to provide a regex that _would_ allow no number because that's what made sense to me.

Comment: I have given input as 6734568975,2643394784 and it gives false

Comment: @SwatiAwasthi - When I copy and paste the input string from your comment into a test of my regex it works (returns `true`) as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/pWSxW/

Comment: @SwatiAwasthi you should accept the answer if this ans has solved ur problem!

Comment: @nnnnnn if i have to make space optional before and after comma, what changes i have to do in the provided regex

Comment: Something like this (untested): `/^(\d{10}( *, *\d{10})*)?$/` will allow zero or more space characters immediately before or after the comma. If you want to allow exactly one or none then change each `*` to a `?`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding one regular expression for the whole thing, you could just split it up and test an expression for each segment, drop the bad ones and stitch the thing back together. This way you can theoretically match hundreds of phone numbers :)

```
var numbers = 'aaa,456,789'.split(',').filter(function(item) {
    return /^\d{10}$/.test(item)
});

if (numbers.length > 2) {
    // too many numbers?
} else if (!numbers.length) {
    // no numbers?
}

// this will give you back a comma separated list in a string
// numbers.join(',')
```

Note that [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) may not work on <strike>evil</strike> all browsers, so you'd have to find a [suitable alternative](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/02/filter-array-using-javascript.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
/^\d{10}(,\d{10})*$/
```

`\d{10}` matches 10 digits

`(,\d{10})*` matches `,` and 10 digits 0 to many times

Answer (score 0):

Similar to others, but without having to repeat the `\d{10}` part

```
^(?:\d{10},?\b)+$
```

Comment: But that doesn't work. You've made the comma optional, so the regex will accept 20-digit numbers, 30-digit numbers, etc. (Also, what's the `\b` near the end for?)

Comment: @nnnnnn Doh! That's why it's always good to test first and not rush to post.

Comment: Ah, nice. Now that it's in the right place I see what you were doing with the `\b`. +1.

Comment: I want comma optional only, if user want he/she can enter only one phone number also

Comment: @SwatiAwasthi comma is optional. The `?` makes it optional

Comment: I provided 1234567890,1234567789 as input it is giving false

Comment: @SwatiAwasthi It returns true for me. See [http://regexr.com?32up9](http://regexr.com?32up9)

Comment: @Swati - I think you're doing something wrong in the way you're using the regex, given that you said mine didn't work either. (It does.) Perhaps you should update your question to show how you're using them.

Comment: Sorry there was one id mistake in my code, it is working fine. Thanks a lot and sorry for above confusion

Answer (score 0):

A validation function for your phonenumbers. If the field is left empty this validates to true.

```
function validateNumbers( text ) {
    var numbers = text.split(",");

    for( var i = 0, len = numbers.length; i < len; i++ ) {
         if( !/^\d{10}$/.test( numbers[i] ) ) {
             return false;
         }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following regex patterns:

- `/^(\d{10}(,(?=.))?)+$/`
- `/^(\d{10}(,(?=.)|$))+/`
- `/^(\d{10}(,(?=.)|))+$/`
- `/^\d{10}(,\d{10})*$/`